# Addin url paramater to current page(header location)

Tags: php, url

Instead of making few header location like:

```
 header("Location: pagename.php?alert=xxxx");
```

I want to add ?alert=xxx to current opened page, how to do it?

Comment: can you show your PHP & HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `PHP_SELF`

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['alert']){
    header("Location: ".{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}."?alert=xxxx");
}
```